# Get Network properties of machine

Tags: c#

i am looking for class that can show me all the Network properties of machine:
Ip's, 
Default Gateway, 
Mac Address, 
Default Gateway, 
Adapter Speed, 
etc..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information using the  [NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) class.

Getting Information about IP addresses is demonstrated here: [IPInterfaceProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.aspx)

To get Link speed, you can need to use [Windows Management Interfaces (WMI)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-WMI-with-C-4e5a9ee1).  As a starting point for your research, you'll want to run this WMI query:

```
SELECT NdisLinkSpeed FROM MSNdis_LinkSpeed
```

Then convert it to MB/s with:

```
SpeedInMbps = NdisLinkSpeed / 10000
```